# Suppress startup status message in mongod

Tags: mongodb, init.d

I'm setting up `mongod` to run in an `/etc/init.d` script. This may be a nitpick, but is there a way to avoid this?

```
# service mongod start
Starting mongod:
forked process: 19820
all output going to /log/location/mongod.log
[SUCCESS]
```

Instead, I just want to see:

```
# service mongod start
Staring mongod:              [SUCCESS]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to change the line in your init.d script to something like this:

```
/path/to/mongod > /dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

That should suppress the output from mongod and just leave you with the output from the script. (the [SUCCESS] message)

Answer (score 0):

`mongod` *does* take a `--quiet` flag; have you tried using that?

Comment: yes, quiet only makes the log quieter